# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, xampp

El error completo es: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\software\EjerciciosDeTransferencia (v3)\src\lib\config\conexion.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\software\EjerciciosDeTransferencia (v3)\src\lib\config\conexion.php(7): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bancomysavings') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\software\EjerciciosDeTransferencia (v3)\src\index.php(98): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\software\EjerciciosDeTransferencia (v3)\src\lib\config\conexion.php on line 7 el código desde el cuál se geenra el error es:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_NAME','bancomysavings');

$link=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: No se puede conetar a la base de datos".mysqli_connect_error());
```

como hago para solucionar ese error y todos los que se me pueden llegar a presentar al ejecutar le programa
}

```
?>
```

el código del software está en el sigueinte link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtIvByYRNlpUgYNaTqNYzvd6Btc4Jw?e=7JMo6L;; cuando intalé MySQL puse usuario y contraseña y en el archivo del programa cambié el usuario y root como el de la contraseña; eso intenté, la respuesta que me dió Bdeaver fue: [image: respuesta de dbeaver al intentar verificar uusario y contraseña si saber como crear una base de datos para el programa de este problema];

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, este error sucede cuando estas intentando ingresar con un usuario que **Si tiene contraseña**, en tu archivo de configuraciones intentas acceder con usuario `root`, y sin contraseña. Revisa las configuraciones de tu base de datos, y las contraseñas de los usuarios.

Comment: No entiendo qué tiene que ver DBeaver aquí ¿? Nos estás mostrando una base de datos en SQLite, ¿esa es la BD a la que quieres conectar? ¿No es `bancomysavings` una base de datos creada en MySQL? Intenta acceder a MySQL por consola, y verifica que dicha base de datos existe, que el usuario `root` existe y que tiene una contraseña en blanco, pues son las credenciales con las que estás intentando conectar.

Comment: como creo esa base de datos?